# Avoid history table explosion for long-running cyclic processes?

Tags: java, business-process-management, camunda

I have a process which has a conditional loop iterating each 1 minute. The process itself can run for weeks, but I expect 99% of it's the history to be a repeating entries reflecting invocation of executions which are the part of the said cycle. Example:

```
|15:34:30.167|15:34:30.238|TimerCatchEvent|
|15:34:30.258|15:34:30.323|CheckConditionServiceTask|
|15:34:30.371|15:34:30.410|ExclusiveGateway1|
|15:34:30.457|15:34:30.501|ReturningtoTimerEventServiceTask|
|15:35:30.167|15:35:30.238|TimerCatchEvent|
|15:35:30.258|15:35:30.323|CheckConditionServiceTask|
|15:35:30.371|15:35:30.410|ExclusiveGateway1|
|15:35:30.457|15:35:30.501|ReturningtoTimerEventServiceTask|
|15:36:30.167|15:36:30.238|TimerCatchEvent|
|15:36:30.258|15:36:30.323|CheckConditionServiceTask|
|15:36:30.371|15:36:30.410|ExclusiveGateway1|
|15:36:30.457|15:36:30.501|ReturningtoTimerEventServiceTask|
```

Is there any way to somehow collapse these repeating history entries on the camunda level? Or maybe someone had come up with other solutions to this problem?

P.S. This is a follow-up for the question on cross-process synchronization: [Cross-process synchronization in Camunda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864943/cross-process-synchronization-in-camunda) - I have implemented what I need using post-fact timer-based "are all ready to sync?"-check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also delete history entries from the database using some clean-up-script. It is safe to delete information from the history - it will not affect the runtime behavior.

Cheers
Bernd

Comment: Thanks, actually, I'm thinking now of exactly the same solution

Comment: I mark this reply as an answer as it is best fits in my situation

Answer (score 2):

In Camunda the History is Event Driven. It is possible to

1. implement a [custom HistoryLevel](http://docs.camunda.org/7.3/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-history-and-audit-event-log-implementing-a-custom-history-level) controlling the amount of events produced and the data they contain,
2. implement a [custom History Backend](http://docs.camunda.org/7.3/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-history-and-audit-event-log-providing-a-custom-history-backend) which allows you to logg the events in a different way than the default handler does.

Maybe that is useful to you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though I think that the only practical solution will be just disabling history events for certain executions - I can't come up with any solution on how should I collapse multi-executions loops using either HistoryLevel or HistoryBackend.